# .NET 6 API System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, autofac

I have Autofac module like this on one class:

```
  public class AutofacBusinessModule:Module
  {
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
      builder.RegisterType<ProductManager>().As<IProductService>();
      builder.RegisterType<EfProductDal>().As<IProductDal>();

      builder.RegisterType<CategoryManager>().As<ICategoryService>();
      builder.RegisterType<EfCategoryDal>().As<ICategoryDal>();

      builder.RegisterType<CustomerManager>().As<ICustomerService>();
      builder.RegisterType<EfCustomerDal>().As<ICustomerDal>();

      builder.RegisterType<RegionManager>().As<IRegionService>();
      builder.RegisterType<EfRegionDal>().As<IRegionDal>();

      builder.RegisterType<TerritoryManager>().As<ITerritoryService>();
      builder.RegisterType<EfTerritoryDal>().As<ITerritoryDal>();

      builder.RegisterType<ShipperManager>().As<IShipperService>();
      builder.RegisterType<EfShipperDal>().As<IShipperDal>();

      builder.RegisterType<EmployeeManager>().As<IEmployeeDal>();
      builder.RegisterType<EfEmployeeDal>().As<IEmployeeDal>();



      var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
      builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces()
        .EnableInterfaceInterceptors(new ProxyGenerationOptions()
        {
          Selector = new AspectInterceptorSelector()
        }).SingleInstance();
    }
```

My API code its there:

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class ProductsController : Controller
  {

    private readonly IProductService _productService;
    public ProductsController(IProductService productService)
    {
      _productService = productService;
    }

    [HttpGet("getall")]
    public IActionResult GetAllProducts()
    {
      var result = _productService.GetAll();
      if (result.Success)
      {
        return Ok(result);
      }

      return BadRequest(result);
    }
  }
}
```

I add this on program.cs but didn't work, if lower I use .net 6 I fix it like that but I don't know how to fix .net 6 because startup doesn't exists anymore.

```
IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
  Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
    .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder =>
    {
      builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacBusinessModule());
    });
```

How can I fix this?

It gives me that error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'TAO.Business.Abstract.IProductService' while attempting to activate 'TAO.WebApi.Controllers.ProductsController'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method3(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

## HEADERS

> Accept: */*
> Connection: keep-alive
> Host: localhost:7019
> User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.30.0
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Postman-Token: fbff062e-ca49-4f37-afc5-e8785afbd43c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code from [migration doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

```cs
builder.Host.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());

// Register services directly with Autofac here. Don't
// call builder.Populate(), that happens in AutofacServiceProviderFactory.
builder.Host.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(builder => builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacBusinessModule()));
```

Note that the "old" generic hosting model still works in .NET 6, there is no requirement to use the new minimal hosting model (but you need to copy not only `CreateHostBuilder` method but also contents of old `Program.Main` into the new `Program` top-level statement file).

Comment: @moongazing was glad to help. if answer works.for consider to mark it as accepted one (checkmark to the left)